# Backticks not right in sql string

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm using Jamie Rumbelow's MY_Model and needed to add a function so that it would include some additional data.

I saw this post and it helped me find out what it is I needed to accomplish this but I'm getting an SQL error. Any ideas on what is wrong?

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM (`titles`) JOIN `users` ON `titles`.`creator_id` =
>   `users`.`user_id`' at line 2

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name)` AS creator FROM (`titles`) JOIN `users` ON `titles`.`creator_id` = `users`.`user_id`

public function with_creator()
{
    $this->db->join('users', 'titles.creator_id = users.user_id');
    $this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS creator");

    return $this;
}
```

When I use Jamie's MY_Model I use the following code.

```
// In controller
$pages = $this->pages->with_creator()->get_all();

// In Model
class Pages_m extends MY_Model 
{
public $_table = 'pages';
public $primary_key = 'page_id';

public function with_creator()
    {
        $this->db->join('users', 'pages.creator_id = users.user_id');
        $this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS creator", FALSE);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And it now only inclucdes the create index and doesn't include any of the data from the pages themeselves.

Comment: The second backtick after `last_name` is outside the right paren.

Comment: I'm not sure why that's like that.

Comment: It's wrong. (Thought it might be a typo)

Comment: That's the exact query that I'm using. No typos.

Comment: Who is Jamie Rumbelow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in CodeIgniter's active record / query builder itself. It is unrelated to Jamie's base model. The bug happens because the `SELECT` string is broken down using `explode()`, with commas as the separator. Since there are commas in the functions, it yields some goof-ups in certain scenarios.

You have two options:

1. Write the query manually. You don't *have* to use the query builder all the time, especially if you're only targeting a single type of database (a big feature of the query builder is to make your application DB-agnostic).
2. Tell the query builder to not escape that particular `SELECT` call. You can do this in two ways:

Array syntax:

```
$this->db->select(array("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS creator"));
```

Escape parameter:

```
$this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name) AS creator", FALSE);
```

This bug should be corrected in CI 3.0 when it becomes stable. It hasn't been fixed in the dev version yet, but the problem is known, it just needs to be ironed out and merged. If you have any feedback, [you can contribute here](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/pull/1612).

**Select problem:** The query is only returning your `creator` concat result because that's all you're requesting. The `get_all()` method does not automatically select everything, that's just the standard default for the query builder. Once you specify a `select()` call, it uses that instead of the default `*`.

You should modify the `select()` (or add another one) to make sure the other columns are called correctly.

Comment: There is an additional issue with this though. Check out the edit.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're referring to. I don't see anything new.

Comment: You're overwriting the `SELECT` portion of your query. See my edit.

Comment: You need to specify your other columns in a `select()`, either the one you're already using with `CONCAT`, or by adding another one elsewhere.

Comment: So should I create another function called get_title_data and do select statement for that.

Comment: That's up to you, however you prefer to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Your query has a backtick on a wrong place. Fix like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', `users`.`first_name`, `users`.`last_name`) AS creator 
FROM (`titles`) JOIN `users` ON `titles`.`creator_id` = `users`.`user_id`
```

Comment: $this->db->select("CONCAT_WS(' ', users.first_name, users.last_name') AS creator");   I'm still missing something somewhere.

Comment: Now you just have one quote after last_name. They have to match.

Comment: I've been trying so many different things in the past hour. No solutions as of yet.

Comment: Stop trying, start understanding. The query I put in my answer is syntactically correct.

Comment: And, if Jamie Rumbelows MY_Model generates that SQL from those PHP calls, there is a serious bug in it.

Comment: I'm trying to figure this out using active record.